# Hazelcast c.h.webmonitor.service.DataService - Error calling operation detectVersionMismatch: null

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, vert.x, hazelcast-cloud

i am using Hazelcast 3.12.2 and management center 3.12.2 running all this using docker-compose , while i use 2 images things are working fine and if i am scaling up my application image with 4 then i am facing issue

eg : i have two images of vertx and springboot if i use one image of each then things are working fine and if i scale it up to 2*2 then facing problem

Cluster size 3 is working but going beyond that is giving me below problem

```
2022-05-17 19:31:15,939 34748 [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.MC.State.Sender] INFO c.h.client.impl.ClientEngine [] - [172.18.0.7]:5701 [dev] [3.12.2] Applying a new client selector :ClientSelector{any}
hz-mc | 2022-05-17 19:31:15 [qtp667821226-66] ERROR c.h.webmonitor.service.DataService - Error calling operation detectVersionMismatch: null
hz-mc | java.lang.NullPointerException: null
hz-mc | at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.utils.Collections$MappedMemberMap.get(Collections.java:77)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.clusterVersion(DataService.java:387)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.detectVersionMismatch(DataService.java:354)
hz-mc | at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
hz-mc | at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.utils.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:70)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.invokeMethod(DataService.java:207)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.service.DataService.getResponse(DataService.java:177)
hz-mc | at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.controller.api.MainController.executeOperation(MainController.java:50)
hz-mc | at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
hz-mc | at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
hz-mc | at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
hz-mc | at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:786)
hz-mc | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:743)
hz-mc | at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```